# undeclared identifier on a string delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I really need some help i am desperate for a solution!

I have a offline messenging form/unit. It will not allow me to compile.

Here is the full code:

http://beyluxe.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mine/OfflinesUnit.pas

I get the following errors:

```
Build
  [Error] OfflinesUnit.pas(103): Undeclared identifier: 'LoadString'
  [Error] OfflinesUnit.pas(142): Undeclared identifier: 'LoadString'
  [Fatal Error] MainUnit.pas(480): Could not compile used unit 'OfflinesUnit.pas'
```

Error 1:

```
procedure TOfflinesForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  PMText: string;
begin
  for i := 0 to OfflineList.Count - 1 do
  begin
    OfflineListView.Items.Add;
    OfflineListView.Items.Caption := OfflineSenders.Strings;
    OfflineListView.Items.SubItems.Add(OfflineList.Strings);
    Viewer.LoadString(PChar(OfflineList.Objects), '', HTMLType);
    Viewer.SelectAll;
    PMText := Viewer.SelText;
    Viewer.SelLength := 0;
    Viewer.Clear;
    OfflineListView.Items.SubItems.Add(PMText);
  end;
end;
```

Error 2:

```
procedure TOfflinesForm.SendTextToViewer(User, Text: string; UserColor: TColor);
var
  Str: string;
begin
  Str := '<B><font size=0 color=#' + IntToHeWebColor(BUDDYNICKCOLOR, 8) + '>' +
    User + ':</font></B> ';
  Str := Str + ReplaceSmilesText(' ' + Text);
  // Str := CorrectHTMLLinks(Str);
  Viewer.LoadString(Str, '', HTMLType);
  Viewer.VScrollBarPosition := Viewer.VScrollBar.Max;
  Viewer.Invalidate;
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]", including the links at the bottom, and "[mcve]".

Answer (score 5):

The error message is clear enough. Whatever `Viewer` is, it does not have a member named `LoadString`, or perhaps that it has a member of that name that is declared to be `private`.

Here's the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/E2003_Undeclared_identifier_'%25s'_(Delphi)) for the error:

> The compiler could not find the given identifier - most likely it has been misspelled either at the point of declaration or the point of use. It might be from another unit that has not mentioned a uses clause.

You need to examine the type declaration for whatever type `Viewer` is, and work out why you expect `LoadString` to have been declared when the compiler says otherwise. Obviously we cannot answer that specific point because we don't have the information required. You omitted those details.

But the point is that you now know what the error message is, and you will now be able to work out why your code is in error.

Comment: http://beyluxe.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mine/OfflinesUnit.dcu that's the link to the full code David Heffernan if you could help please? :(

Comment: I answered the question that you asked. I don't want to get into onwards debugging of the rest of your code.

Comment: Ok, If i cannot fix it would you be willing to fix it for a fee?

Comment: @TyroneSummers: that link is for downloading a precompiled DCU file, not for downloading Pascal source code. You probably meant http://beyluxe.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mine/OfflinesUnit.pas instead

Comment: No. I'm sure you can fix it if you look at your code. Start by working out what `Viewer` is, as I said.

Comment: In this case, based on the code in `OfflinesUnits.pas`, `Viewer` is a `THTMLViewer` from the `htmlview` unit, which I'm **guessing** is this one: https://github.com/BerndGabriel/HtmlViewer/blob/HtmlViewer-11.6/source/htmlview.pas, which does have a `LoadString()` method: `procedure LoadString(const Source, Reference: ThtString; ft: ThtmlFileType);`

Comment: @Tyrone: This is not a *rent a programmer* site. Everything done on this site is done here, on this site. If you want to hire a coder, go elsewhere. If you want help here, include the necessary information in your question. As David said, you've provided no indication of what *Viewer* is or whether it actually has a *LoadString* method.

Comment: So what do you want me to include? I just provided the link to the full code and it was removed.

Comment: @Remy: That's an assumption (which is probably correct), but for this question to be useful to future readers we shouldn't have to assume anything; the relevant information should be in the question.

Comment: No, you linked to a compiled .dcu file.

Comment: @Tyrone: The variable definitions of the data types you use (eg., *Viewer*) would be a good place to start. We should not have to leave this site to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: Ok so what should i include here? i am totally new to delphi! :(

Comment: It's a instant messaging program that i plan to open for a local charity here in the UK for disabled young people to discuss and communicate

Comment: Offlinesunit is so somebody can send you a message whilst you're offline and you can view it when you are online again

Comment: We aren't here to write your code for you. If you cannot understand my answer, then you are not ready to write this code. You need to back up and do some more learning. If you cannot understand what that error message tells you then you should not be writing code in this language.

Comment: Ok sorry to offend anyone, David Heffernan i'm only trying to help people in need, this is the only error i couldn't fix.

Comment: Did you read my answer? Did you understand any of it? What did you not understand?

Comment: @TyroneSummers: Please confirm whether or not the `THTMLViewer` component used in your code is the same `THTMLViewer` component that is available at https://github.com/BerndGabriel/HtmlViewer/.  If so, then you are likely not using an up-to-date version of it, because the version on that site *DOES* have a `LoadString()` method. The error message you are seeing says the component you are currently using *DOES NOT* have a `LoadString()` method.

Comment: I'm just waiting for a friend who's involved in this with me to help me out here, I just wanted to know exactly how to fix this string error, i understand you guys have put a lot of help into this question and i do really really appreciate that! :) sorry for any sillyness from me.

Comment: Can I ask again if you read and understood what I wrote. We are interested in helping people learn.

Comment: No david, i'm understanding Remy Lebeau more, i guess i may have installed the wrong component or an old version of it! :)

Comment: `LoadString` in the latest is private. If you cannot understand what I wrote, then you aren't ready to proceed. Blindly trying stuff without understanding isn't really productive. Why not stop and think a little. Try to think what *Undeclared identifier* means. Have you done that yet? Or did you just see an error message and stop? Because error messages can be understood. It's worth getting past that beginner's fear of error messages.

Comment: Ok thanks @David Heffernan this is my only issue i know you guys arn't here to write the fix/code for me, im sure it will compile once this issue is resolved.

Comment: And no i understand the error i'm just not skilled enough to fix/work it out.

Comment: Great. You understand the error. Now that you understand the error you'll appreciate that you can never call `LoadString` because it is private. You'll need to change your code, and not the component. Updating the component to the latest (if it is not already so) is probably worthwhile, but then again, the person that wrote the code perhaps intended for a different version to be used. You should ask the author of your code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the author provides no support at all.

Comment: Then you are probably in trouble. Because you'll need to obtain a version of the component which exposes `LoadString`. You might need to look for an old version rather than go to the latest.

Comment: @TyroneSummers: the `THTMLViewer` component that is on GitHub is a continuation of PBear's component.  In both components, `LoadString()` is declared as `protected`, I did not notice that earlier. However, I see both components do have public `LoadFromString()` and `LoadStrings()` methods. If you need to specify an HTML type, you will have to use the GitHub component, as the PBear component does not have that parameter. Otherwise, just omit that parameter: `Viewer.LoadFromString(PChar(OfflineList.Objects), '');`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I used you're code and this is what happend: [Error] OfflinesUnit.pas(103): '[' expected but ')' found
[Error] OfflinesUnit.pas(142): '[' expected but ')' found
[Fatal Error] MainUnit.pas(480): Could not compile used unit 'OfflinesUnit.pas'

Comment: Should be `Viewer.LoadFromString(PChar(OfflineList.Objects[i]));` and `Viewer.LoadFromString(Str);`, respectively.

Comment: @TyroneSummers - how are you getting on?